# Is there any way to recover files from github and local machine that has been accidentally removed?

Tags: python, git, github

While pushing a large file to the github, accidentally all main files that i uploaded got removed from github repo and from my local machine too.

I am trying reverting but not working.
Please, help if anyone can.

I used these commands

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git fetch origin master 
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories 
git add filename 
git commit -m 'new_weights' 
git push origin master -f
```

Comment: What commands did you use to remove files?

Comment: I hope you didn't use `rm - rf`

Comment: Go back to the last commit you have made before deleting the file.

Comment: @Kaushal first: i use `git rm -r --cached .` `git fetch origin master`
`git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`
`git add filename`
`git commit -m 'new_weights'`
`git push origin master -f`

Comment: check the `git log` and reset to last_commit_hash. `git reset <commit_hash>`